# Changing closeBox color of ol-ext PoupFeature in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, popup, css, ol-ext

I'm using the PopupFeature from the ol-ext library with Openlayers. Where can I change the color of the popup close button?

```
  var popup = new ol.Overlay.PopupFeature({
    popupClass: 'default anim',
    closeBox: true,
    select: select,
    template: function(f) {
      return {
        title: function(f) { return f.get('nom')+' ('+f.get('id')+')' },
        attributes: { 
          region: { title: 'Région' }, 
          arrond: 'arrond', 
          cantons: 'cantons', 
          communes: 'communes', 
          pop: 'pop' 
        }
      }
    },  
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change the popup close button background color in CSS.

To set close button color to red:

```
.ol-popup .closeBox {
  background-color: red
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thsnk you, I didn't know where I should chance in the css.